# How to intract with contract wihout private key?

Tags: solidity

I saw many example of implementation of smart contract for example this : https://dev.to/bhaskardutta/signing-message-using-metamask-in-flutter-1o37

but I am confuse why we need private key and how our do
intract with smart contract method just with metamask
or without private key

Answer (score 1):

One private key can be transformed into one public key. One public key can be transformed into one public address. Therefore one private key results in one public address.

If you want to change the blockchain state (often through contracts), you need to have the private key to a public address which has some Ethers to pay for gas costs. Then you issue a transaction from that account (public address) and that transaction modifies the blockchain state.

You can read from the blockchain without a private key because read operations are for free.

Metamask is basically just a fancy way of utilizing private keys and to connect to the blockchain. So when you create a new account in Metamask, it generates a new private key for you which it then utilizes.